# Как пометить различия в строках?

Tags: python, pyqt

Подскажите, нужно подсветить пользователю различия в результата сравнения двух фреймов

```
             df2 = pd.read_excel(self.filename1, skiprows=2, header=None, usecols=[3, 4, 5, 20]).drop(labels=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],axis=0)
             df3 = pd.read_excel(self.filename2, header=None, usecols=[3, 4, 5, 12]).drop(labels=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],axis=0)

             result = df2.loc[df2.ne(df3.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]
             result2 = df3.loc[df3.ne(df2.to_numpy()).any(axis=1)]

             datafr = pd.concat([d.reset_index(drop=True) for d in [result, result2]], axis=1)
```

, что бы пользователь видел именно те места где они отличаются друг от друга, что для этого лучше использовать?

Я вижу это так вывожу результат в QTtextEdit а данные которые отсутствуют в сравниваемом столбце помечаются в столбце по которому сравниваем.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обнаруживать различия вы уже научились? Я спрашиваю чтобы понять - это вопрос про отображение различий (нужно подсветить известные места в тексте) или про поиск этих самых мест?

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и ответьте на вопрос из первого комментария.

Comment: Можно воспользоваться модулем [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.ndiff) вот пример  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17904977/4711135

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Обнаруживать различия вы уже научились? да привёл код обнаружения этот вопрос про отображение различий

Comment: @S.Nick дополнил вопрос кодом

Comment: @АполлинарийКодоправ, я не сомневался что вы умеете сравнивать строки на (не)равенство.  я спрашивал умеете ли вы для двух неравных строк выделять фрагменты в которых они различаются. Да или нет?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy к сожалению нет

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html

Comment: Еще немного теории: при вычислении [расстояния Дамерау — Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83_%E2%80%94_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0) можно явно выделить какие символы были вставлены, какие удалены, какие заменены или переставлены.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy поставьте пожалуйста  эти 2 комментария в ответ.